# pass runtime argumets in servlet

Tags: java, servlets, struts

Iam trying to develop a web application, where when a button is clicked the servlet has to be started with some command line arguments. This is required as the servlet class runs a corba client. The servlet class cannot invoke the corba client without these command line arguments " `-ORBInitialHost xxx.xx.xx.xx -ORBInitialPort 1050`" where x's are the ip address.The program runs fine when i execute it as a standalone java application with the following command "`java HelloClient -ORBInitialHost xxx.xx.xx.xx -ORBInitialPort 1050`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your `ORB` and pass it those parameters as Java `Properties`. Something like:

```
...
Properties props = new Properties();
props.add("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", httpServletRequest.getParameter("initialHost"));
props.add("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", httpServletRequest.getParameter("initialPort"));
ORB orb = ORB.init(null, props);
// do some work with your ORB
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass them as request parameters and then use them when invoking the corba client.

For example, the url being `http://domain.com/corbaServlet?param1=foo&param2=bar` and then

```
public void doGet(..) {
    String param1 = request.getParameter("param1");
    String param2 = request.getParameter("param2");
    startCorbaClient(param1, param2);
}
```

Comment: But the arguments i mentioned are command-line arguments, How will the jvm know about these if they are passed as formal parameters to the method. If u can notice the second command in case of standalone application.

Comment: you said you are starting the corba client from your servlet. So I assumed you are running Runtime.exec(..). If not, please clarify your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add them as system parameters to the application server startup scripts and retrieve them in the servlet using system.getProperty()?

```
java -Dorb.host=xxx.xx.xx.xxx -Dorb.port=1050 application_server_startup.jar
```

and in your servlets init() method

```
orbHost = System.getProperty("orb.host");
orbPort = System.getProperty("orb.port");
```